# Flutter package Geolocator not showing current location

Tags: flutter, geolocator

I am learning Flutter and trying to rebuild Clima project following londonappbrewery's flutter course. After I installed the geolocator package and invoked the getCurrentPosition method, I got nothing.

The geolocator version is ^9.0.2 with flutter 3.10.6 and I'm testing on a physical device.

[geolocator package problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHYEh.png)

```
void getLocation() async {
    LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    print(permission);
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);
    print(position);
}
```

I manually asked permission from the device, but it's still not working.

This is what I add to the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also check the Location Service status. Try this code:

```
Future<Position> determinePosition() async {
  final serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();

  if (!serviceEnabled) {
    return Future.error('Location service is disabled.');
  }

  var permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();

  if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
    permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      return Future.error('Location permission is denied forever.');
    }
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      return Future.error('Location permission is denied.');
    }
  }

  return Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
    desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low,
  );
}
```

And change your permissions in AndroidManifest.xml to:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

With `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` only it might take a long time (minutes) before you will get your first locations fix.

If this doesn't help, check that all the rest [plugin's requirements for Android](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) are met.

Comment: The link does work. I re-config my project according to the link you provided and re-factor my method to check the permission first and manually get permission like this `void getLocation () async {
    LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if(permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      print('Permission denied!');
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    }
    Position location = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
    print(location.latitude);
  }` All good now. Tks!